# Limpiar campos al deseleccionar un selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, primefaces, checkbox, spring-webflow

tengo un problema que no se resolver ahora mismo. Tengo un formulario donde estoy usando PrimeFaces y xhtml y Java y SpringWebflow de back y bueno hay un campo que es `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` el cual cuando se selecciona aparecen unos campos y cuando se deselecciona, desaparecen pero necesito "limpiar" los campos que aparecen, ya que si los relleno y quito el check y lo vuelvo a poner, al aparecer los campos, están rellenos.

Gracias de antemano.

[image: El método que tengo ahora]

[image: La parte de front (xhtml) donde llamo al método mediante un ajax]